# DropDownList inside Grid

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET, I have a dropdownlist inside of a grid (radGrid).

What I like to happen is that when the dropdownlist appears, I like it to default to 
"Please Select" only if the field that it is binding to is blank. Else, I like to to get the value from the DataSource.

I have the following code:

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEroGroup" runat="server"  DataSourceID="EroGroupSource"  DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnDataBound=" erogroupDropDown_DataBound" Text='<%# Bind("EroGroup") %>'>                            
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

For the DataSource here is the code:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="EroGroupSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ISQL %>"        
        SelectCommand="Select Value from LookupValues where Category = 'EroGroup'"> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the code in the code-behind:

```
    protected void ErogroupDropDown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;

        if (list != null)
        {
            list.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", ""));
        }
    }
```

When it does the Binding, if the value is blank, I get an error saying that it could not find the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid PreRender event for this. May you would need to assign the value to some hidden label and access it inside prerender method and assign it to the dropdown.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblValue" Text='<%# Eval("YourValue")%>' Visible="false" />
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEroGroup" runat="server"  DataSourceID="EroGroupSource"  DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnDataBound=" erogroupDropDown_DataBound" Text='<%# Bind("EroGroup") %>'>                            
     </asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="EroGroupSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ISQL %>"        
        SelectCommand="Select Value from LookupValues where Category = 'EroGroup'"> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</ItemTemplate>
```

On code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int i=0;i<Gridview1.Rows.Count;i++)
   {
       Label lblValue = (Label)Gridview1.Row[i].FindControl('lblValue');
       DropdownList ddl = (DropdownList) Gridview1.Row[i].FindControl('ddlEroGroup');
       ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", ""));
       if(lblValue!=null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblValue.Text))
            ddl.SelectedValue = lblValue.Text;

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I think my question is if I do the Bind and if the value is blank, how do I default it to Please Select?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 protected void ErogroupDropDown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;

        if (list.Items.Count.equals(0))
        {
            list.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", ""));
        }
    }
```